# C# BinaryWriter - and endianness

Tags: c#, endianness, binarywriter

I am using BinaryWriter in my code, here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"F:\testfile");
    if (file.Exists) file.Delete();
    using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(file.Create()))
    {
        ushort a = 1024;
        ushort b = 2048;
        bw.Write(a);
        bw.Write(b);
        bw.Write(a);
        bw.Write(b);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

But the hex of the output file is :

[image]

[image]

Isn't that 0x0004 = 4?  why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Although 1024 is `0x0400`. When it comes to storing this in file or memory,
question comes should we use little endian or big endian notation?

In case of `BinaryWriter`, it is little endian. Which means LSB goes first - then comes the MSB.
Hence, it is stored as:

```
LSB | MSB
00    04
```

You can read more about endianness.

Comment: I know this is a little late, but as for the BinaryWriter and any other writer class use the constructor that takes a encoding too.. Then use Encoding.BigEndianUnicode to write in big endian instead.

Comment: @kam have you tested this? The Encoding.BigEndianUnicode is simply a test encoding for when you call WriteString(). I very seriously doubt that it affects endianness on other methods, especially since MSDN doesn't mention it.

Answer (score 11):

As a sidenote, it writes to the file **exactly** as it is specified in the [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8sh9zw1e.aspx):

> **Remarks**
>
> BinaryWriter stores this data type in little endian format.

What you asked for is "big endian format". You'll have to reimplement the `BinaryWriter` to do it.

Note that `BinaryWriter` has a different behavior from `BitConverter`. `BinaryWriter` is "always little endian", while [`BitConverter.GetBytes(ushort)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8wwsdz3k.aspx) (that is a totally different function but that has a "common" connection: converting numbers to bytes) is "local-endian" (so it uses the endianness of the computer)

> **Note**
>
> The order of bytes in the array returned by the GetBytes method depends on whether the computer architecture is little-endian or big-endian.

In the end on Intel/AMD PCs this difference is moot: Intel is Little Endian, so are nearly all the cellular phones. The only big exception that I know that supports .NET (in a special version) is the Xbox360.

Answer (score 4):

If I'm not mistaken, in the display the endian-ness of the output is reversed with respect to your expectation. Although the hexadecimal representation of `1024` is `0400`, it might be stored as `0004`, depending on the endian-ness of the encoding or platform.